# How to redirect all long urls to their shorter versions?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I would like to redirect all unknown URLs for example like this:

```
http://www.website.com/title/.../...
```

to like this:

```
http://www.website.com/title
```

I tried an `.htaccess` file that looks like this but it doesn't seem to work:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)/.*$
RewriteRule ^.*/(.*)$  /$1 [R=301]
```

What am I missing?

Comment: It's not very clear what you are trying to do at all. What does *"call everything longer"* mean? What URLs do you want a browser to see vs what URLs actually point to the desired resources?

Comment: I have lot of long urls generated by CMS indexed by search engines. I would redirect all these long urls to the standard short version of url I am using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that you want the first title, this should work:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)/.*$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

For the index.php:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=302,L]
```

Comment: Thanks Prix, that is great! it works exactly I need 99%. Only http://www.website.com/index.php/.../... is not redirected to http://www.website.com/index.php. I dont know why, I will try to explore other rules in my .htaccess.

Comment: Because index.php is a valid file and `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` will prevent valid files from redirecting, you would need a different rule for that.